# Modular Routing with React Router V6 and useRoutes?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I come from the angular world and I'm trying to setup a modular routes using react router v6 new useRoute hook.

App.js

```
function App() {
const [item, setItem] = useState(null);
    const createUser = async (user) => {
        await axios.post(AUTH_API + '/account', user);
    };
    
    let routes = useRoutes([
        {
            path: '*',
            element: <NotFound404 />,
        },
        {
            path: '/register',
            element: <Registration onCreateUser={createUser} />,
        },
    ]);
    return routes;
}

export default App;
```

In these routes I want to import the routes of my item domain:

ItemRoutes.js

```
export const itemRoutes = [
  {
    path: 'edit-item',
    element: <ItemEdit setItem={setItem} item={item} />,
  },
];
```

How can I import itemRoutes.js into the routes array of app.js  As you can see the ItemEdit components expects the setItem and item hook. But those are provided in App.js...
Is this even possible?

Comment: You could create a React context for the `item` state, that the `ItemEdit` component  consumes. This avoids the issue of passing props.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a React context for the `item` state, that the `ItemEdit` component consumes. This avoids the issue of passing props.

Example:

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

const ItemContext = createContext({
  item: null,
  setItem: () => {}
});

const useItemContext = () => useContext(ItemContext);

const ItemContextProvider = ({ children, value }) => (
  <ItemContext.Provider value={value}>{children}</ItemContext.Provider>
);
```

- Import and spread the `itemRoutes` into the routes array in `App`.
- Wrap the `App` render with the `ItemContextProvider` component and pass `item` and `setItem` as the context value.

...

```
const itemRoutes = [
  {
    path: "edit-item",
    element: <ItemEdit />
  }
];
```

...

```
import { itemRoutes } from '../path/to/itemRoutes';

function App() {
  const [item, setItem] = useState(null);

  const createUser = async (user) => {
    await axios.post(AUTH_API + '/account', user);
  };

  const routes = useRoutes([
    {
      path: "*",
      element: <NotFound404 />
    },
    {
      path: "/register",
      element: <Registration onCreateUser={createUser} />
    },
    ...itemRoutes
  ]);

  return (
    <ItemContextProvider value={{ item, setItem }}>
      ...
      {routes}
      ...
    </ItemContextProvider>
  );
}
```

EditItem should use the `useItemContext` hook to destructure and access the `item` state and the `setItem` state udpater.

Example:

```
const ItemEdit = () => {
  const { item, setItem } = useItemContext();

  return (
    <>
      <h1>ItemContext</h1>
      <div>Item: {item}</div>
      <div>
        <label>
          Edit item:{" "}
          <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setItem(e.target.value)} />
        </label>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit modular-routing-with-react-router-v6-and-useroutes]